# popToViewController can't switch between views

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have this function in an IBAction button:

I start off with a table with a button, when that button is pressed this takes place:

```
TabBarController *v = [[TabBarController alloc] 
                          initWithNibName:@"TabBarController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: v animated:YES];
[v release];
```

On the second view there is another button which when pressed does this:

```
NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

[self.navigationController 
    popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

This causes the app to crash, and at index 0 it does nothing.  Is this because the second page is not a UITable like the first?

I want to be able to move from UITable view to UIView back and forth, should I use `addSubview` instead?  I need the first view to have a navbar but the second shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `[array objectAtIndex:1]` is your current ViewController, so popping to the current view controller might be the reason of your crash (did not try it though)

So why don't you do:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add the following line in button code and it will work fine

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];